# Why does ptr_fun(tolower) doesn't compile in mingw?

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm trying to compile the following program using Qt Creator 2.0.1:

```
void f()
{
    string a = "abc";
    transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), ptr_fun(tolower));
}
```

mingw throws the following error:

**no matching function for call to ptr_fun( < unresolved overloaded function type > )**

That function compiles fine with VC++ 2010 Express. What is wrong with mingw?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the ambiguity introduced by the function template

```
template <class charT> charT tolower(charT c, const locale& loc);
```

I guess that mingw has included `<locale>` indirectly from one of the headers your program includes, whereas VC++ didn't.

You can fix this by disambiguating `tolower` with a cast:

```
typedef int (*foo)(int);
ptr_fun((foo)tolower);
```

Or if you like maintenance programmers to throw shoes at you:

```
ptr_fun((int (*)(int))tolower);
```

Note that as Armen says, you don't actually need `ptr_fun` here. It converts a Unary Function into an Adaptable Unary Function, but `transform` doesn't need its parameter to be adaptable. The difference is whether the type has nested typedefs for `argument_type` and `result_type`. Raw function types don't, `ptr_fun` returns a functor type that does.

Finally, it's not in general safe to call the C `tolower` on a `char` if `char` is signed on your platform. Your example string is OK, because none of the characters in "abc" is negative, but you should do something like this:

```
char fixed_tolower(char c) {
    return tolower((unsigned char)c);
}

transform(..., fixed_tolower);
```

Or for a better chance of inlining:

```
struct fixed_tolower : unary_function<char, char> {
    char operator()(char c) const {
        return tolower((unsigned char)c);
    }
};

transform(..., fixed_tolower());
```

I haven't checked whether it actually makes any difference in GCC, either from the POV of inlining or from the POV of whether the mingw implementation of `tolower` actually barfs on negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call

```
transform (a.begin, a.end(), a.begin(), tolower);
```

?

Comment: for reasons unconnected to the question, is why not ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with mingw. There are multiple overloads for `tolower`, generating the message "unresolved **overloaded** function.

You need to specify *which* overload you want to use, eigher via some cast `(int)(*)(char)tolower` or an intermediate variable.